# Java FileWriter refusing to overwrite

Tags: java, filewriter

I'm very confused...

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Testing overwrite");

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("c:\\testing\\testfile.txt", false);

        writer.write("First test");
        writer.flush();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

        writer.write("Second test");
        writer.flush();

        writer.close();

    }

}
```

After completion, the contents of the file is:

```
First testSecond test
```

The boolean passed to the `FileWriter` with the value of `False` should be causing an overwrite, not an append, according to the Java docs here: [Java 6 Filewriter API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean))

I've had this problem in the past, and I've used a `RandomAccessFile` to bypass the problem, but now it's just annoying me!

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you manually set the `offset` using [`write(String, int, int);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write(java.lang.String, int, int))?

Comment: I know see that as an option.  So I'd have to store the String prior to using it, and then pass in it's length to the write?

Comment: The manual offset method still results in an append.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When calling 
`FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("c:\\testing\\testfile.txt", false);` it will overwrite the file. It won't overwrite per `.write`. The option only applies for the contructor.

Comment: Ahh I see.  In that case, either I misunderstood, or it's a bit misleading.  So what's the best mechanism for overwriting the file each time?

Comment: Probably to `.close` and reopen the the file with `new FileWriter` for every time you want to overwrite.

Comment: That does the job.  Seems I misunderstood the filewriter.  I'll just recreate it before each write.  Thanks for clearing that up!